# Preventing JPEG Compression artefacts during binarization

Tags: opencv, jpeg

I am trying to use an binarize images similar to the following image:

[image: color image]

Basically, I want all non white to become black but `threshold` in OpenCV is giving fringing (JPEG Artifacts). I even tried Otsu thresholding but some parts of the colors don't work so well.

Is there any simple way of doing this binarization properly?

Comment: avoid jpeg compression ;)

Comment: I wish I could... Unfortunately, all the original images are jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some trial and error, turns out Morphological Closing before thresholding using a large value turns out to be most suitable for the next stage of what I am working on. But it does cause some loss of shape info.

Answer (score 1):

Turn to greyscale, apply 5x5 blur filter, and binarize? The blur will smooth the ringing artifacts.

Comment: The blur causes it to have larger size than I want, but Morphological close seems to work decent enough. Thanks though :)

Comment: @JayBosamiya: Then try a 3x3 blur. I picked 5x5 because the JPEG blocksize is 8x8.

Comment: Tried different sizes for blur and morphological transforms... Then I talked to the guy giving me the images - said he was sending the jpegs because the bmp's were too big... Told him to send pngs instead... Problem solved :)

As always, the problem was between keyboard and chair :D

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have to use JPEG for this project, the one thing you can do use all one quantization tables. That is usually done through "quality" settings. You want an encoder that will allow you to do no quantization.